# Numbering in nested lists

Tags: lists, enumerate, tags

Is there way to modify according to this example the tags to each item?

```
\documentclass[8pt,a4paper,dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumitem} 


\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
\item{One.} Here I would like keep both parentheses.
\item{Two.}
\begin{enumerate}[label*=(\roman*)]
\item Two.one; here, However, I would like remove parentheses between 'b' and 'i'
\item Two.two
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `label*` you can use

```
[label=(\alph{enumi}\,\roman*)]
```

[image]

### Notes:

- I added a small space `\,` between the `b` and the `i`, but you can adjust that as desired.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem} 

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
\item{One.} Here I would like keep both parentheses.
\item{Two.}
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph{enumi}\,\roman*)]
\item Two.one; here, However, I would like remove parentheses between 'b' and 'i'
\item Two.two
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```